# Inserting logs with count

Tags: nosql, redis

In the website I am working on, there is an search API. I want to log all the activities with Redis but I have no clue how to store such data into redis. There should be search query and count, and it can be ordered by count to see the most searched queries. I would be thankful if you can show me the proper way.

Comment: Did you go through [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/documentation) or [quickstarts](http://openmymind.net/2011/11/8/Redis-Zero-To-Master-In-30-Minutes-Part-1/)? It's a fairly easy task to do with `SortedSet`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sorted set.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY searches 1 foo
"1"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY searches 1 bar
"1"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY searches 1 baz
"1"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY searches 1 foo
"2"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY searches 1 foo
"3"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY searches 1 bar
"2"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGE searches 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "foo"
2) "3"
3) "bar"
4) "2"
5) "baz"
6) "1"
```